# Why does ZFC need an axiom schema of specification?

Tags: set-theory

The axiom schema of specification is redundant given that, as seems to be generally understood, the power set axiom guarantees the existence of all subsets.

Comment: The powerset axiom tells you that there is a set of all subsets. It doesn't tell you that any particular subsets exist.

Comment: Given an arbitrary predicate, $\phi$, what proof in ZFC without specification shows that exactly one member of the powerset contains exactly the elements satisfying $\phi$?  Could zero members do so?  Could two?  Could infinitely many?  You and I know only one member does so; how does ZFC know that?  To rephrase: ZFC without replacement has no way to relate (arbitrary) predicates and (not necessarily finite) sets.  The underlying logic can resolve the question for finite starting sets, but not necessarily for infinite starting sets.

Comment: Thanks to Zhen Lin for a very precise and succinct answer to the question.

Answer (score 4):

Let $\alpha$ be any limit ordinal. Let's study the structure $(\alpha,\in)$.

1. It satisfies Extensionality, as any linear order does.
2. It satisfies Power Set, since if $\beta\in\alpha$, the only subsets of $\beta$ which are elements of $\alpha$ are other ordinals, so $\beta+1$ is the power set of $\beta$.
3. If $\alpha>\omega$, then Infinity also holds.
4. Separation fails: the only object which does not contain the empty set (as an element!) is the empty set itself, and so $\varphi(x)=\exists y(y\in x)$ is a fairly simple formula, but $\{x\in\beta\mid\varphi(x)\}$ is not a set, as far as $\alpha$ is concerned, whenever $\beta\geq2$.

So, you see, Power Set does not imply Separation. It is true, however, that Replacement implies Separation. And so it is, in some sense redundant. Once we get into weaker set theories, however, this redundancy becomes helpful. Which is one of the reasons it stuck around for so long.